# How to run external program after python program executes

Tags: python

When i try to run something like

```
os.system('start')
```

or

```
os.system('start file.txt')
```

or

```
os.startfile('file.txt')
```

it does start console, notepad or whatever, but when my python program executes, those opened programs close as well.
So my question is: Is there a way to do things like above, but without closing those programs along with my script?

Comment: It seems like you think "executes" means "stops running". For programmers, it normally actually means "starts running" or "continues to run".

Comment: This is simply untrue.  You can run Python from your command line, type `import os`, `os.system("start notepad")`, then Ctrl-Z to exit the interpreter, and the Notepad command will continue happily running..

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the reason why it didn`t work for me was that my script was run in vs code.

Answer (score 1):

It will work with frunction from the `subprocess` module.
Here is an example with `Popen` :

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen(['notepad.exe'])
```

You can also use `call`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['calc.exe'])
```